# How can I save SPSS data by appending data into an excel/access file instead of saving a new file each time?

Tags: syntax, odbc, spss

I run SPSS syntax to manipulate data and then I wish to save the data. This is the code that I am now use to save data from SPSS:

```
SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE='/filepath/excel_file.xlsx'
  /TYPE=XLS
  /VERSION=12
  /MAP
  /REPLACE
  /FIELDNAMES
  /CELLS=VALUES.
```

However, using this means I create a new excel file or replace the existing file every time I run this syntax. Is there any way I can append the new data in the same file without erasing the old data? The file in the end can either be in excel or access.

Answer (score 1):

With Statistics version 24, you can update an existing Excel file directly with a new sheet without using ODBC.  In the Export dialog, specify a sheet name and check "Append sheet to existing file".  The syntax might look like this.

[image]

Comment: Does the bitness of Statistics and Office need to be match for this feature?

Comment: That's a great feature - good to know! Jon, "The syntax might look like this" sounds like you intended to add some sample syntax?

Comment: Did you not see the syntax?  I added it as an image to take advantage of the color coding.

Comment: Jignesh, No the bitness does not matter, because SAVE  TRANSLATE writes the file directly rather than through ODBC apis.

Comment: Huh, you're right - for some reason the image didn't show the first time I looked...

Comment: @JKP : I have SPSS version 20. Is there a way to do this in version 20 without using ODBC? I tried implementing the answer that suggests the ODBC route but couldn't get the required results.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using ODBC:

To first create a new worksheet in your Excel file use:

```
SAVE TRANSLATE /TYPE=ODBC
  /CONNECT='DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=c:\filepath\excel_file.xlsx;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;'
  /ENCRYPTED
  /MISSING=IGNORE
  /REPLACE
  /TABLE='WorksheetName'
  /KEEP=var1, var2, var3 .
```

Next time, when you want to append to the same worksheet, instead or `REPLACE` use `APPEND`:

```
SAVE TRANSLATE /TYPE=ODBC
  /CONNECT='DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=c:\filepath\excel_file.xlsx;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;'
  /ENCRYPTED
  /MISSING=IGNORE
  /APPEND
  /TABLE='WorksheetName'
  /KEEP=var1, var2, var3.
```

Note that some of this is version specific (SPSS and Excel). To create your own syntax use 
FILE > EXPORT > EXPORT TO DATABASE
select EXCEL FILES and click NEXT, then follow through with the rest, and paste to syntax.

**ADDITION**
I would suggest to accumulate you data in an SPSS file also:

```
prepare your data...
*if the ODBC export works for you, export now using `/append`.
add files /file=* /file="filepath\your previous accumulated data.sav'.
save outfile="filepath\your previous accumulated data.sav'.
*if you have trouble with the ODBC export, you can just save the whole accumulated file to excel.
```

Comment: Remembering, the bitness (32bit vs 64bit) of your SPSS Statistics and MS Office have to be a match for this to work. If you are stuck on a 32bit MS Office for whatever reason then it's a case of installing SPSS Statistics 32bit.

Comment: @eli-k I ran the syntax the way you mentioned but I got an error that said the `ODBC subsystem has issued an error which prevents the processing of SAVE TRANSLATE ODBC request`. Also, the error read `Data source name not found and no default driver specified`. Could you please provide steps to setup this connection or any resource that has this information?

Comment: Also, @eli-k , when I go to `FILE > EXPORT > EXPORT TO DATABASE` , I do not have the "Excel Files" option. Could you please let me know how I can get this option?

Comment: I actually don't know enough to help you in this problem. I suggest you add this as a separate question. In that question please post also what your operating system is and if it is 32 or 64 bit, and your versions of office and SPSS.